# an annotation to avoid setter method?

Tags: spring, inject

If I specify what should be injected into a property, like

```
<property name="xxx" ref="some_bean" />
```

or

```
<property name="xxx">
     <bean .../>
</property>
```

then I have to write a setter method.

May I use some annotation to avoid this like `@autowired`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with constructor injection.  3 main ways to do this:

XML:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="com.BeanA">
    <constructor-arg ref="beanB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="beanB" class="com.BeanB"/>
```

JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {
        return new BeanA(beanB());
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanB beanB() {
        return new BeanB();
    }
}
```

Autowiring:

```
@Component
public class BeanA {
    private final BeanB beanb;

    // This assumes that there is a BeanB in your application context already
    @Autowired
    public BeanA(final BeanB beanB) {
        this.beanB = beanB;
    }
}
```

You can take Autowiring even further, and wire directly to the field:

```
@Component
public class BeanA {
    // This assumes that there is a BeanB in your application context already
    @Autowired
    private final BeanB beanb;
}
```

Comment: I think it's more complex than adding a setter method. Actually what I want is an easy way to omit unnecessary code.

Comment: Use `@Autowired` on a private field, then (the last example here)